# How to make a UIWebView in the DetailView of a Split View display data for a corresponding UITableViewItem selected in the Root View

Tags: xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad app. In the Root View I have a UITableView with two levels. I need to display different webpages in the UIWebView in Detail View based on the selected UITableView row. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the web view to somewhere accessible from the root view controller's table view delegate with interface builder (if you're using IB).

In your root view controller's table view delegate's `-…didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, load the new page for the web view depending on the selected index path.

Comment: But, as I've mentioned, I have a two-level UITableView, so -...didSelectRowAtIndexPath: won't work

Comment: @Knodel: You can determine whether you're in level 1 or 2 in `-…didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @Knodel: How do you implement the root view controller for 2 levels?

Comment: I have a UITableViewController with 9 rows and 9 more corresponding UITableViewControllers

Comment: @Knodel: Then you need to load the new page in the `-…didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` of the 9 corresponding UITableViewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this TableView method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSURL *urlStrg= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.ca"];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlStrg];
        [self.detailViewController.detailItem loadRequest:urlRequest];
    }else if(indexPath.row == 1) {
        NSURL *urlStrg= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.ca"];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlStrg];
        [self.detailViewController.detailItem  loadRequest:urlRequest];
    }else {
        NSURL *urlStrg= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.ca"];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlStrg];
        [self.detailViewController.detailItem  loadRequest:urlRequest];
    }
}
```